# When I try to change my global variable from a function in my script nothing is happening?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my Notepad app and in the `ChangeSize()` function I am trying to change the size of the font and the function is activated on the press of the Label Size in the bottom, but its not doing anything!

Can someone Tell me why the `ChangeSize()` function is not working?

```
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, Menu, filedialog, END, messagebox, simpledialog
import os

root = Tk(className=" TEXT EDITOR")
root.title("Untitled.txt - TEXT EDITOR")

F_size = 20
F_family = "Ubuntu Mono"
F_weight = "bold"
F_font = (F_family, F_size, F_weight)

textArea = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=80, height=30, font=F_font)

#Functions
def ChangeSize():

    global F_size
    F_size = 50

# Menu Options
helpMenu = Menu(menu)

menu.add_cascade(label="Text Options", menu=helpMenu)

helpMenu.add_command(label="Size", command=ChangeSize)
```

Comment: Changing a variable doesn't magically change everything that the previous value of the variable was used for.  You would have to update `F_font`, and then update your widget with the new value of `F_font`.

Comment: I am kinda new in python so can you show me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: For the first part: `F_font = (F_family, F_size, F_weight)` (exactly like you originally set the variable); for the second: `textArea.config(font=F_font)` or `textArea['font'] = F_font`.

Comment: Thank You soo much!!

Comment: @jasonharper: while what you suggest will work, it's much better to use font objects for custom fonts, rather than a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're doing is changing a variable. You need to change either the widget or a font object used by widgets.

Tkinter has a very powerful mechanism for managing fonts. You can create font objects and associate them with widgets. Then, whenever you change the font object, all widgets that use that font will automatically adapt to the change.

For example:

```
from tkinter import font
...
f_font = font.Font(size=20, family="Ubuntu Mono", weight="bold")
textArea = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(..., font=f_font)
...
def ChangeSize():
    f_font.configure(size=50)
```